# Setting a JWT token in header from localStorage for redirect

Tags: authentication, jwt, frontend

I am using JWT tokens to authenticate users and protect certain routes.
My app is set up with a login function that receives a username and password from the front end, authenticates the user and passes back a token.
I am able to store my token in localStorage like this.

```
localStorage.setItem("Token", token);
```

Any ajax call going forward should be able to use

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: '/protected_route,
  headers: {
   "Accept": "application/json",
   "Token" : localStorage.getItem(Token),
   success: (data) => {
    // do something with the data
   }}
```

This should work as long as the token is still set in localStorage and not expired. My question is, if I want to redirect right after login to a protected path, how would I do that?

```
window.location = '/my_profile
```

does not let me set headers.
I am surprised that I could not find anything regarding this issue. Seems like very common use case when using JWT.
Thanks!!

Comment: If this page is not accessible via API with a token, you can set a cookie, and authenticate the request based on that

Comment: Thanks @abdusco. I’m sure that would work. The point is however to build token based authentication. All requests need to have the token in the header.